# switching between graphic drivers (Intel & Radeon)

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, radeon, hybrid-graphics

I would like to use my Radeon GPU for ever. I have followed [these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics#How_to_switch_the_GPU).
But seems it's not working for me.
Here is the output of lspci after doing that steps:

```
$ lspci -nnk | egrep -i --color 'vga|3d|2d' -A3 | grep 'in use'
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

What i tried is:

for configuring `SWITCHEROO`, I replaced `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=1"` in `/etc/default/grub`.

And after that I ran these commands:

```
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo su
# sudo echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
# reboot
```

but after rebooting and checking `lspci`. I saw that current kernel driver in use is still `i915` which is my Intel HD Graphic!

I'm sure that `SWITCHEROO` is configured correctly (Based on the docs).

## Edit:

I have a laptop with hybrid graphics (Asus R540). which has a `Intel HD Graphics 620` and a `Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230`.

here is the full output of `lspci -k`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5286 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5286 PCI Express Card Reader
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
02:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Comment: What is the GPU model that you have?  Do you have a laptop with hybrid graphics or is this a desktop computer with a truly dedicated GPU? Please edit your question and include more details about your hardware so that we can understand the problem more completely.

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for asking. edited.

Comment: Hybrid graphics laptops often need to have the GPU enabled/disabled in firmware.  Have you checked with the documentation for your laptop to make sure that the GPU is enabled?  If it is disabled at the firmware level, Ubuntu won't be able to use it.

Comment: i think its enabled. i have installed ubuntu alongside windows 10. in my windows i dont have any problem and play games on my radeon graphic driver

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Are there any BIOS updates available for your device?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 21.10. And please don't ake me about updating BIOS. Because I updated the BIOS once and because other versions of the BIOS were not compatible with my laptop, my laptop did not turn on and I had to reinstall the default BIOS from the motherboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132554/discussion-between-qafoori-and-nmath).

Comment: Well you **never** use a BIOS for a different model. You should **always** follow the manufacturers directions to flash a BIOS and don't interrupt a BIOS flash. You are very lucky that you did not brick your board. In any case, your device may require an updated BIOS for hardware compatibility. If there is a BIOS update available for your model then you should update.  Make sure you download the correct file for your exact model and follow their instructions carefully and completely

Comment: So do you think the only way to fix this issue is updating BIOS? Is there no less risky way?

Comment: It's not risky if you obtain the correct file and follow the instructions. If your BIOS is outdated and you are having problems hardware detection or compatibility, then you should update it